# How do you set up Jade file watcher in Webstorm?

Tags: node.js, pug, webstorm, file-watcher

I set up a Jade file watcher in the [following way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEz0Y.png) in WebStorm. However it does not produces any HTML files.

How is it possible to convert Jade file to HTML file with WebStorm 9.0.3?

Answer (score 14):

You have specified a wrong path to Jade in a Program field.
Do you have Jade installed globally? Please run `'npm install jade -g'`, then test jade in your system terminal by running `'jade <your jade file>.jade'`. Then specify a path to installed jade script as a 'Program' in your file watcher

Comment: Is there an option to indent/auto-format the generated HTML file ?

Comment: @DioPhung open the HTML file, go to the code bar on the top menu, and click reformat code.